# How can ec2 instances in private and public subnet communicate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Can any body let me know how can ec2 instances in private and public subnet communicate with each other ?

Answer (score 2):

Instances under a private and public subnet of the same VPC can by default communicate. This is handled within the Route Tables of the VPC. If you want to change it, that is where you would do it I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If they are residing within the subnets of same VPC then they can just communicate as if they are within the same subnet

Comment: Just to clarify, with the same vpc 1 ec2 is within the public subnet and the other in private subnet with port 22 open for both instances via security group. I can reach 1 instance from another?

Comment: Yes, if the public and private subnet that you are referring to reside within the same VPC

Comment: If I want to perform a computation in the instance in private subnet and return the result back to the system in public subnet, how can I do that? I am not getting any clue.

Comment: What protocol do you want to use for the communication

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Henry's answer,

You need to check the ports in `Security Group` if you want EC2 instances are not  communicating properly.

If instances are sharing the same Security Group then it's easy for you to manage the port settings of your EC2 instances. If they are using different Security Groups then check your port settings carefully.

For example, if you want to ping to other EC2 instance, and you are not getting the response, then the first thing to check is *Security Group* and check the port. Check the `inbound ICMP` port, add the entry if not present and then try to ping again. You will get response this time.